# Using jQuery to prevent form submission when input fields are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

The solution should be pretty straightforward. I'm trying to prevent the form from submitting properly when no value is found within the input boxes. Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nArYa/7/

//Markup

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form">
<input type="text" placeholder="Your email*" name="email" id="email">
<input type="text" placeholder="Your name*" autocomplete=off name="name" id="user_name"
<button type="submit" id="signup" value="Sign me up!">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

//jQuery

```
if ($.trim($("#email, #user_name").val()) === "") {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');
    })
}
```

As you can see in the JSFiddle, the problem is that when I type something into both fields, the alert box STILL pops up. I'm having a hard time figuring out why. Is there something wrong within my
    **if($.trim($"#email, #user_name").val()) === "")** ?

Comment: Yes you should check each of them individually, if you only use one selector, only one value will be returned

Comment: From the documentation: Get the current value of the **first** element in the set of matched elements

Comment: You need to attach a javascript function to your submit button.

    <button onclick="somefunction();" .. />

Where the function returns false if the fields are not valid.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Two things, #1 the check for empty fields should happen on every attempt of submit, #2 you need to check each field individually

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#user_name").val()) === "") {
        alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');
        return false;
    }
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nArYa/12/)**

Comment: It's working directly implement code                               if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#user_name").val()) === "") {
        alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');
        return false;
    }

Answer (score 8):

Your check occurs on page load. You need to check the field when the form is submitted.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    if ($.trim($("#email, #user_name").val()) === "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

HTML5: use **required** in input tag

- A boolean attribute.
- Input field must be filled out before **submitting** the form.
- Works with text, search, url, tel, email, password, date pickers, number, checkbox, radio, and file.

  ```
  <input required type='text'...>
  ```

[w3schools hint](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: What about entering just spaces? I just used this but it still submitting when entering blank spaces in the input fields.

Comment: Then You can use Pattern attribute along with required. http://www.felgall.com/html5r.htm will help you. (not supported by safari browser)

Comment: Example with pattern attribute to disallow whitespace only submits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17323588/1879699

Answer (score 4):

I guess that this will help:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#email, #user_name").each(function(){
        if($.trim(this.value) == ""){
            alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');
        } else {
            // Submit 
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your if statement inside the callback:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#user_name").val())) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');
        //You can return false here as well
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not the right answer, will submit even if username is empty